# R-class not created

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-plugin

I have recently installed android dev-tools for Eclipse - using a new OS - ubuntu. I am coming from the windows enviroment.

When I developed my first testapp - Strangely the R-file is not created at all. Thats seems to be the missing part. I have tried to clean the project but no R-class is autogenerated.

What is the problem - what did I miss and how is it fixed?

Comment: the problem might be that there is a problem -> if there is an issue like a missing library, a syntax error in your java, you are using a different sdk, didn't install the sdk you build against, etc etc, the R class cannot be generated. Impossible to say which it is (so it doesn't help to say for instance no libraries are missing, that was just an example). Find out what errors your set-up has apart from the errors caused by the missing R. Don't forget the clean, rebuild and restart-eclipse steps .

Answer (score 0):

Go to `project > properties > java build path > order and export`

Move `gen` to above `src`